# Is it a good practice to use lazy() and Suspense for image loading?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component which loads some images. It's not expensive at all, but I don't want them to appear one by one from top to bottom, if you know what I mean. Is it considered a bad practice to use `lazy()` and `Suspense` for that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: no that's not a bad practice, and it's common

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have specific component for rendering Image in react , the best ways of lazy loading is using `lazy() import` or `Suspense` .
Although , there is a more recent way of doing this with **HTML** and it is appropriate for inline `<img/>` tags.

```js
<img loading="lazy"/> 

// also works for iframe
<iframe loading="lazy"/>
```

**keep in the mind that this attribute, at present , is only available in `chrome` and `firefox`**